# Property Grid:Dispay a property value only if it is not null

Tags: user-interface, controls, propertygrid, .net

I am using property grid (System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid) in one of the UI to display the properties of a class.
At times there is a possibility that some of the property of the object I want to display is a null value.
So here I see a row for this property in the propertygrid and value is empty.
Is there any option to hide this property when it is null.

Comment: I could see that the property can be hidden from displaying by using Browsable property. But how can it be done depending on the value of the property?

Answer (score 0):

The Browsable attribute in propertydescription can be set through reflection and you can hide the value.

http://codinglight.blogspot.de/2008/10/changing-attribute-parameters-at.html